# R - split data frame without removing NA values

Tags: r, dataframe, split, na

If I have a df:

```
letter    body_part
    a     head
    b     head
    c     NA
    d     NA
    e     left_foot
```

And I want to split it into 2 dfs... One with only body_part - "head" and the other with everything else. I.e.

> list <- split(df, df$body_part == 'head')

Can I do that without dropping the NA rows? (I know I can do it if I fill the NAs with a string, but is there a way that avoids that step?)

Comment: `split(df, df$body_part %in% 'head')`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From `` ?`%in%` ``:

> That ‘%in%’ never returns ‘NA’ makes it particularly useful in
>        ‘if’ conditions.

```
# just to show how the `==` comparison compares  
> df$s_col <- df$body_part == 'head'

> split(df, df$body_part %in% 'head')
$`FALSE`
  letter body_part s_col
3      c      <NA>    NA
4      d      <NA>    NA
5      e left_foot FALSE

$`TRUE`
  letter body_part s_col
1      a      head  TRUE
2      b      head  TRUE
```

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - why add the `df$s_col` ?

Comment: Your answer output assumes such a column is there, if I read correctly.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - fair enough, I forgot that I had run your answer's code before pasting the answer. :-)

Comment: Yep this is great!

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the `f` argument of `split()` to factor while not exluding the `NA` values.

```r
df <- read.table(h= T, strin = F, text = "
letter    body_part
    a     head
    b     head
    c     NA
    d     NA
    e     left_foot")

split(df, factor(df$body_part,exclude = NULL))
#> $head
#>   letter body_part
#> 1      a      head
#> 2      b      head
#> 
#> $left_foot
#>   letter body_part
#> 5      e left_foot
#> 
#> $<NA>
#>   letter body_part
#> 3      c      <NA>
#> 4      d      <NA>
split(df, factor(df$body_part,exclude = NULL) == 'head')
#> $`FALSE`
#>   letter body_part
#> 3      c      <NA>
#> 4      d      <NA>
#> 5      e left_foot
#> 
#> $`TRUE`
#>   letter body_part
#> 1      a      head
#> 2      b      head
```

<sup>Created on 2019-10-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

```
> ind <- df$body_part == 'head'
> ind[is.na(ind)] <- FALSE
> split(df, ind)
$`FALSE`
# A tibble: 3 x 2
  letter body_part
   <chr>     <chr>
1      c      <NA>
2      d      <NA>
3      e left_foot

$`TRUE`
# A tibble: 2 x 2
  letter body_part
   <chr>     <chr>
1      a      head
2      b      head
```

Comment: "*I know I can do it if I fill the NAs with a string, but is there a way that avoids that step?*"