# NA incorrectly appearing in selected/subsetted data

Tags: r

I'm stumped by the following:

```
z <- data.frame(a=c(1,2,3,4,5,6), b=c("Yes","Yes","No","No","",NA))

is.na(z$b)
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE

z$a[z$b=="Yes"]
[1]  1  2 NA

is.na(z$a[z$b=="Yes"])
[1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

Why is it that when I select `z$b=="Yes"`, NA appears as a third value for the subsetted `z$a`?

When I subset, however, this isn't a problem:

```
subset(z, b=="Yes")$a
[1] 1 2
```

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: You need `z$a[z$b=="Yes" & !is.na(z$b)]`  to create a vector of TRUE/FALSE. because NA remains as NA with `z$b == "Yes"`. `subset` filters out the `NA` rows

Comment: @akrun I can definitely select out the NA results, but it still seems like odd behavior to me because I'm asking for z$a values and there is no NA in z$a.

Comment: As I said you check the output of `z$b == "Yes"`, Whereever there is NA, it is an NA.  So, the safe option would be to change it to FALSE with `& !is.na(z$b)` or use `subset` or `dplyr::filter`

Comment: You can also use `%in%` to avoid this - `z$b %in% "Yes"` for instance - which will not return `NA` values. See - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44710627/r-split-data-frame-without-removing-na-values/44710782

Comment: You can also use `which()` to avoid this: `z$a[which(z$b=="Yes")]`